# How to make a function run a number of times that is randomly generated

Tags: javascript, random

I am making a game in which there will be a random number generated, and I want that many random numbers generated. So for example if the number is 6 i want 6 *more* random numbers to be generated. So is there a way to run a function containing this (and a few other things) X numebr of times?

Just a code example:

```
let circNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4 + 3 )
let circles = function() {
  //generate circNum random numbers
  //make circNum new divs
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a `for` loop?

Comment: You can do it by recursion but when it will stop?

Comment: Not the best answer. Just a suggestion. How about you create a loop  and call function in it and let the loop have its count be determined by the random number you generate.

Comment: please add the interval for the random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do the job.

1. rangeLow is the low range of the number of random generated numbers.
2. rangeHigh is the high range of the number of random generated numbers.
3. randRangeLow is the low range for the value of the random generated numbers.
4. randRangeHigh is the high range for the value of the random generated numbers.

   ```
   function randomGen(rangeLow, rangeHigh, randRangeLow, randRangeHigh) {
       let randArray = [];
       for (i = 0;i < Math.floor(Math.random() * (rangeHigh - rangeLow + 1) + rangeLow);i++) {
           randArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (randRangeHigh - randRangeLow + 1) + randRangeLow));
       };
       return randArray;
   };
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
   var arr = []
   while(arr.length < 6){
      var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*100;
      if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
      arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
   }
   document.write(arr);
```